# mongo update query to ignore few fields in update operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoskin

I am using Nodejs based mongoskin driver for mongo database operation. I want to update my document however don't want to update few fields. Following are more details.

**Request for add:**

```
{
  "name": "Theme Name",   
  "description": "Theme Description",
  "createdByUserId": "53651221b25521601a5c9530",    
}
```

**Request for update:**

```
{
  "_id":"53555ef203dabf282b750a81"
  "name": "Theme Name",
  "categoryId": "53555ef203dabf282b750a81",
  "description": "Theme Description",  
  "createdByUserId": "53651221b25521601a5c9530",
  "updatedByUserId": "5675561b25521601a5c9530",
  "dateCreated": ISODate("2014-05-19T19:47:26.603Z"),
  "dateUpdated": ISODate("2014-05-19T19:49:28.203Z"),
}
```

I want to ignore following field send by client.
1. createdByUserId
2. dateCreated

For time being I am taking following approach in update operation:
1. Read collection for given _id
2. Read these above two fields from database and update the request and then perform database update operation

Looking help for clean approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your request for update actually does the following: it replaces everything in the document with the values provided by the request (except for the "_id" of course, which is immutable). What you want is what is called a ["partial update"](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/307919034/partial-object-updates-will-be-an-important-nosql) in mongosphere. Please have a look into the [$set operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set). So what you would do is something like:

```
db.yourcollection.update({"_id":"53555ef203dabf282b750a81"},
  {$set:
    {
      "categoryId":"53555ef203dabf282b750a81",
      "updatedByUserId":"5675561b25521601a5c9530",
      "dateUpdated":ISODate("2014-05-19T19:49:28.203Z")
    }
  }
)
```

As far as I know there is now way of sending a complete document to a mongo[s|d] and tell it to only skip certain fields.

Comment: Thanks Markus. I am thinking to create wrapper method to iterate each field of document and create query as you suggested. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Good to know that this is not supported:-)

Comment: You should not need to do this. Since you know which fields are to be updated, simply use `$set` on them and you should be good.

Comment: The link to the blog post in the response is not working. However I googled it and guess the new link is this: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/partial-object-updates-will-be-an-important